# How do I use a large title Navigation Bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

This is what I get when I use CupertinoNavigationBar()

Standard title Navigation Bar -
[image: Standard title Navigation Bar]

This is what I need to implement -
[image: Large title Navigation Bar]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can checkout [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmaGvdLpFPc&ab_channel=AndyJulow) tutorial for the explanation but the code from the tutorial is:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled){
          return <Widget>[
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text('Settings'),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: Center(child: Text('Home Page'),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code makes a large text an appbar with a large title like the following image:

[image: Appbar image]